# Ошибка в django 2.2 NoReverseMatch. Не передает данные в шаблон

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Помогите пожалуйста!
Такая ошибка:

> NoReverseMatch at /others/ Reverse for 'the_code' with keyword
>   arguments '{'num': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['others/the_code/$']

others.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  {% for code in codes %}
  <br><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">{{code.name}}</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>{{code.description}}</p>
          {{code.id}}
          <p><a href="{% url 'the_code' num=code.id %}" class="btn btn-info">Смотреть</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

`{{code.id}}` - выводит на экран правильно.

Если не передавать ничего, `{% url 'the_code' %}` то так все работает. И переходит на нужный шаблон.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import models


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'homepage/homepage.html')


def to_share(request):
    return render(request, 'to_share/to_share.html')


def others(request):
    codes = models.Code.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'others/others.html', context={'codes': codes})


def the_code(request, num):
    code = models.Code.objects.get(id=num)
    return render(request, 'others/the_code.html', context={'code': code})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.others, name='others'),
    path('the_code/', views.the_code, name='the_code'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Code(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)
    prog_lang = models.CharField(max_length=15, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False, db_index=True)
    body_code = models.TextField(blank=False, db_index=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.description)
```

Comment: Ну так в вашем urls.py нету никаких num, отсюда и логичная ошибка

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большое! Оказывается так все просто было. Думал, что urls только для указания шаблонов. 3 дня мучался =))

Comment: @ЮрийВерхотуров а прочитали бы документацию, не мучались бы и минуты.